# Calling a C style function pointer in a WebAssembly from JavaScript

Tags: javascript, c, webassembly

Is there any way to get access to function pointers living inside a WebAssembly module?

For example, given the following "module" compiled to WebAssembly:

```
extern void set_callback(void (*callback)(void *arg), void *arg);

static void callback(void *arg)
{
  /* ... */
}

int main() {
  set_callback(&callback, 0);
  return 0;
}
```

Can an implementation of `do_callback` in JavaScript invoke the callback without having to rely on an intermediary C function export to do the actual function call?

```
var instance = new WebAssembly.Instance(module, {
  memory: /* ... */
  env: {
    set_callback: function set_callback(callbackptr, argptr) {
      // We only got the pointer, is there any  
    },
  },
});
```

By intermediary function export, I mean that I could add an internal function with public visibility.

```
do_callback(void (*callback)(void *arg), void *arg)
{
  callback();
}
```

Then the JavaScript `set_callback` function can call the function pointer via the delegate `do_callback` function.

```
function set_callback(callbackptr, argptr) {
  instance.exports.do_callback(callbackptr, argptr);
}
```

But, it's preferable to do this without having to go through that explicit indirection, is it possible, with function tables maybe?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The issue back then was that Clang basically did not implement call_indirect and did not actually populate the function table with anything during code generation.

Has been resolved in the current version of LLVM.

Answer (score 4):

You can invoke function pointers from Javascript.

Function pointers are stored in a Table.  When a function pointer is passed to Javascript you are receiving the integer index into the table for that function pointer.  Pass that index to `Table.prototype.get()` and you can call the function.

```
...

set_callback: function set_callback(callbackptr, argptr) {
  tbl.get(callbackptr)(argptr);
},

...
```

You can read more about this on this MDN page under the Tables section:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/WebAssembly/Using_the_JavaScript_API#Tables

**Edit:** Here is the minimal example I used to test this.

The first file is `fptr.c` compiled with `emcc fptr.c -Os -s WASM=1 -s SIDE_MODULE=1 -o fptr.wasm`

```
typedef int (*fptr_type)(void);

extern void pass_fptr_to_js(fptr_type fptr);

static int callback_0(void)
{
    return 26;
}

static int callback_1(void)
{
    return 42;
}

void run_test()
{
    pass_fptr_to_js(callback_0);
    pass_fptr_to_js(callback_1);
}
```

And here is `fptr.html`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>WebAssembly Experiment</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h3>Check the console.</h3>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        fetch('fptr.wasm').then(function(response) {
            response.arrayBuffer().then(function(buffer) {
                WebAssembly.compile(buffer).then(function(module) {
                    var imports = {};

                    imports.env = {};

                    imports.env.memoryBase = 0;
                    imports.env.memory = new WebAssembly.Memory({ initial: 256 });
                    imports.env.tableBase = 0;
                    imports.env.table = new WebAssembly.Table({ initial: 4, element: 'anyfunc' });

                    imports.env["abort"] = function() {
                        console.error("ABORT");
                    };

                    imports.env["_pass_fptr_to_js"] = function(fptr) {
                        console.log("table index: " + fptr + ", return value: " + imports.env.table.get(fptr)());
                    };

                    WebAssembly.instantiate(module, imports).then(function(instance) {
                        instance.exports["__post_instantiate"]();
                        instance.exports["_run_test"]();
                    });
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @CasperBeyer I've edited my post to include the working example I used to test this.

Comment: How would I get clang to generate imports for table and memory without Emscripten? Do it at the linker level? e.g wasm-link with an "empty" module containing the imports?

Comment: @CasperBeyer This sounds like a new unrelated question. If you post it as such it will have more visibility.

Answer (score 0):

For some reason, the table approach is not working for me, so I did in the opposite direction: I implemented a function table in my source language (D).

This way, I can make it work by passing handles to javascript:

```
__gshared ubyte* function(ubyte* args)[] _annonymousFunctionTable;
extern(C) size_t _getFuncAddress(ubyte* fn);
export extern(C) ubyte* __callDFunction(size_t addr, ubyte* args)
{
return _annonymousFunctionTable[addr](args);
}
```

I don't call directly _getFuncAddress here because there is another way of sending functions I did for D for argument count and type checking.

This way, I can call any function I would like with how many arguments which I want without depending on the wasm implementation.