# How to resolve function pointers in Rust & WebAssembly

Tags: javascript, pointers, rust, shared-memory, webassembly

I want to provide a WebAssembly module with an external JavaScript function that accepts a Rust function pointer.

Once this JS module is initialized, it will call the `run()` function from the `.wasm` module, and that will in turn call `peekaboo`:

```
window.Module = {};

const imports = {
  env: {
    memoryBase: 0,
    tableBase: 0,
    memory: new WebAssembly.Memory({ initial: 256 }),
    table: new WebAssembly.Table({ initial: 4, element: 'anyfunc' })
  }
};

imports.env.peekaboo = function(f) {
  const fn = imports.env.table.get(f);
  return fn(2);
};

fetch('game.wasm')
  .then(response => response.arrayBuffer())
  .then(bytes => WebAssembly.compile(bytes))
  .then(mod => WebAssembly.instantiate(mod, imports))
  .then(mod => {
    mod.exports.run();

    Module.memory = imports.env.memory;
    Module.dealloc_str = mod.exports.dealloc_str;
  });
```

The examples I've seen indicate that if I import the `memory` in this way, I should be able to use the `table` to resolve my function pointer. Here is the Rust code:

```
#![feature(wasm_import_memory)]
#![wasm_import_memory]

extern "C" {
    fn peekaboo(f: fn(u32) -> u32);
}

fn main() {}

#[no_mangle]
pub fn run() {
    let plus_one = |x: u32| -> u32 { x + 1 };

    unsafe {
        peekaboo(plus_one);
    }
}
```

Everything compiles fine but when I execute the `peekaboo` function, the `fn` variable is `null`, indicating that the table was unable to find the function pointer. Therefore executing `fn(2)` blows up with:

```
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: fn is not a function
```

I more or less followed [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45387728/calling-a-c-style-function-pointer-in-a-webassembly-from-javascript) but since I'm working in Rust, the translation is not 1-to-1. I suspect that I've overlooked something that's not obvious to me because I'm new to both Rust and WebAssembly. Can anyone spot my mistake?

Answer (score 4):

It seems so far the WebAssembly backend in Rust doesn't provide a way import or export the (function) `table`; the index `f` is just fine, but `imports.env.table` is not the same table used by the `wasm` instance (i.e. empty).

Also you should use `extern fn` in FFI.

If you want to take a look under the hood the [Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org) provides some nice WebAssembly optimizations, check out this example:

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=0b38378e1dd9877ad32ac13af71739b2&version=nightly&mode=release)

```
#![crate_type = "cdylib"]
#![feature(link_args)]
#![allow(unused_attributes)] // link_args actually is used
#![link_args = "--import-memory"]

extern "C" {
    fn peekaboo(f: extern "C" fn(u32) -> u32);
}

#[no_mangle]
pub fn run() {
    extern "C" fn plus_one(x: u32) -> u32 {
        x + 1
    }

    unsafe {
        peekaboo(plus_one);
    }
}
```

The result should look like this:

```
(module
  (type $t0 (func))
  (type $t1 (func (param i32) (result i32)))
  (type $t2 (func (param i32)))
  (import "env" "peekaboo" (func $peekaboo (type $t2)))
  (import "env" "memory" (memory $env.memory 17))
  (func $run (export "run") (type $t0)
    (call $peekaboo
      (i32.const 1)))
  (func $playground::run::plus_one::h85275af105f0cc85 (type $t1) (param $p0 i32) (result i32)
    (i32.add
      (get_local $p0)
      (i32.const 1)))
  (table $T0 2 2 anyfunc)
  (elem (i32.const 1) $playground::run::plus_one::h85275af105f0cc85))
```

If you want to reproduce this locally add this in your `Cargo.toml`:

```
[lib]
crate-type = ["cdylib"]

[profile.release]
lto = true
```

And build with `cargo +nightly build --release --target wasm32-unknown-unknown` (assuming a [rustup](https://rustup.rs/) setup with a `nightly` toolchain and `wasm32-unknown-unknown` target enabled for the `nightly` toolchain).

Comment: *using `no_std`* — The correct way is to [generate a dynamic library](https://play.integer32.com/?gist=283ea95febab14842fe0ee0318a413d3&version=nightly). I'm not sure why that information has yet to be picked up by the community.

Comment: Ah, these both look promising, thanks! Can I assume that some of the code in this example is irrelevent? e.g. `eh_personality()`? :)

Comment: @Samo If you use `no_std`, you need to provide some symbols otherwise provided by the standard library for the code to link, including the ones you see in the code here.  I don't know what items exactly are needed; it depends on your code, but you can simply let the compiler tell you.

Comment: @Shepmaster `cdylib` looks fine in the playground, but on my local system I still need `no_std` (and `panic_fmt`) to get rid of a lot of crap.  Thanks for the hint though, wanted to try this for some time and never got around to it.

Comment: @Stefan You also need to use [wasm-gc](https://github.com/alexcrichton/wasm-gc),
 which [the playground uses](https://github.com/integer32llc/rust-playground/blob/master/compiler/base/cargo-wasm#L41-L42).

Comment: Since [wasm_import_memory was removed](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/pull/48125) this example no longer compiles.

Comment: @starwed should be fixed now in the answer... although such things are expected to happen with unstable features :) it also seems wasm-gc isn't needed anymore (at least not for this small example), cdylib and lto are doing a good job.